# google places autocomplete Session token time validation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have created a request for autocomplete using the google-places-api autocomplete that looks like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input="new york"&key=MyToken&sessiontoken=bdb38446-52cd-48b9-89ea-93e55a5c21dd

I ran this request last week and got valid response and ran it again today and got a valid response again with the same sessiontoken.

It is not clear to me when the session token expires. in the documentation it says that the token expires after a few minutes.

Is the sessiontoken valid for a specific IP for eternity ?

Comment: I would expect the documentation to be correct.  Did you get charged for another query?

Comment: @geocodezip I can't see because I am not exceeding the 200$ per month yet

Comment: Did the query appear in the dashboard (it will count the queries even if you are still in the "free" quota, if it counts a new query after the token expires, but not before, that is what matters)

Comment: @geocodezip for each request I made with the same sessiontoken the request count increment by one. so I guess it means that each request is billed as a new sessiontoken  right ?

Comment: That is how I would interpret that, although I would expect multiple requests within a short time of receiving the token would not be counted.